# LinkButton Onclick Download or Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

At the moment i have a link button that when it is clicked it will download a file. Is it possible to have an onclick pop up where the user can select if he wants to download or delete the file?
P.s New to asp.net and C#

```
<asp:GridView ID="FileTableView" CssClass="datagrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="datagridHeader" RowStyle-CssClass="datagridRows" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="fileid, filename">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Master Folder">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="FileLinkButton" OnClick="DownloadFile"  runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("filename") %>' FileID='<%# Eval("fileid") %>'></asp:LinkButton>                
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) to display the modal popup, all you have to do is add these three references to your project:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Complete solution can be found below:

**Code behind:**

```
public class MyFile
{
    public int fileid { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
}

public partial class PopupInGridView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var f1 = new MyFile { fileid = 1, filename = "File 1" };
            var f2 = new MyFile { fileid = 2, filename = "File 2" };
            var files = new List<MyFile> { f1, f2 };

            FileTableView.DataSource = files;
            FileTableView.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void File_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string command = e.CommandName;
        string fileId = Session["fileid"] as string; 

        switch (command)
        {
            case "ShowPopup":
                Session["fileid"] = e.CommandArgument;
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myModal", "showPopup();", true);
                break;
            case "Delete":
                //Your delete logic...
                break;
            case "Download":
                //Your download logic...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showPopup() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView
            ID="FileTableView"
            CssClass="datagrid"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="datagridHeader"
            RowStyle-CssClass="datagridRows"
            runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="fileid, filename">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Master Folder">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkChoice" CommandName="ShowPopup" OnCommand="File_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("fileid") %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("filename") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete or download?</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnCommand="File_Command"  />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument="" runat="server" Text="Download" OnCommand="File_Command" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your own on a new project.. however when i transferred over to my main project it does not seem the pop up, i added System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test"); in the switch case for Showpopup and indeed, Test was printed on the output console. However the pop up box was not showing on my page. What could the reason behide it?

Comment: I've mentioned it in my answer.You need to add three references to your page - jQuery,bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css(in that order).Also you need to make sure that you have a div with an id="myModal".Another thing that might be an issue is that the showPopup() function should NOT be defined inside the jQuery document load event, you should place it outside the load event.Just make sure you have checked all those things and it should work.Remember to mark as answered if it helped you

Comment: Yes i have done all the steps and it still does not pop up, it appears to be refreshing everytime i clicked the button..

Comment: Place a debugger inside File_Command and make sure this line of code is executed and there should be no other logic after that - ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myModal", "showPopup();", true);